# How to use startproject --template? (Django 2.2)

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm attempting to create a Django templates directory via `django-admin startproject` and `--template`.

I've tried: `django-admin startproject main_project --template=./templates`

However it only creates an empty `main_project` directory there is nothing reflecting a Django instance in this directory (ie. no urls.py, settings.py, wsgi.py, etc.)

```
- desktop/
    |_ main_project/ # directory where startproject will be executed via CLI
        |_ templates/
```

I'm expecting a project Python package to be created as described here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/ # or main_project for my example
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

I'm only getting:

```
- desktop/
    |_ main_project/ # directory where startproject will be executed via CLI
        |_ main_project
            |_ #empty directory
        |_ templates/
        |_ venv
```

Comment: If i am not mistaken, you want to create the templates directory through terminal ?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Thats simply not possible. You are starting a whole project just to create a template folder.

Comment: For my project, i navigated to my app and created directory by `mkdir templates` :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-startapp-template

Perhaps try the command with the —template flag before the project name

Comment: What he wants is different from what `--templates TEMPLATE` mean